# Modify Angular 2 Component's HostListener event

Tags: angular

I am looking for a way to modify the trigger event of an existing HostListener in a 3rd party component without modification to the component's source code.

I am using the great UI-Switch for Angular 2 from Yang Yang Yu (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-ui-switch), but I have to support a device were the click event does not fire in the browser. Only mouseup fires (don't ask me for the details, the story is about old touchscreen drivers that I cannot update).

So the question is: Is there a way in Angular 2 to modify the @HostListener during runtime without modifications to the source code (which I would like to circumvent, because of possible future update problems).

The relevant code from UI-Switch:

```
  @HostListener('click')
  onToggle() {
    if (this.disabled) return;
    this.checked = !this.checked;
    this.change.emit(this.checked);
    this.onChangeCallback(this.checked);
    this.onTouchedCallback(this.checked);
  }
```

What do I want to do: I want the @HostListener to listen to the mouseup event, like so:

```
  @HostListener('mouseup')
```

Is there a way to modify other component's @HostListeners during runtime?