# TypeScript | JavaScript | Angular 2: Dynamically Set @HostListener Argument

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive, event-listener

### Dynamically Setting the @HostListener's Arguments

I have a directive which needs to listen for any event provided declaratively by the engineer. Here's an example:

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//--
import { Sandbox } from '../../../sandbox';

@Directive({ selector: '[addItem]' })
class AddNewItemDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input('addItem') data;
    @Input() on: string = 'click';

    constructor(private $: Sandbox, private element: ElementRef) { }
    ngOnInit() { console.log('@INIT', this); }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event']) handleEvent(e) {
        console.log('add-item', e);
    }
}

export { AddNewItemDirective };
```

Here's its usage:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" [addItem]="{ name: 'Jeffrey' }" on="focus">Add New Item</button>
```

This works fine. However, my intuition told me I should be able to dynamically set the HostListener's arguments at render time based upon an input parameter:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[addItem]' })
class AddNewItemDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input('addItem') data;
    @Input() on: string = 'click';

    constructor(private $: Sandbox, private element: ElementRef) { }
    ngOnInit() { console.log('@INIT', this); }

    @HostListener(this.on, ['$event']) handleEvent(e) {
        console.log('add-item', e);
    }
}
```

Of course, `this.on` would not be overwritten with `'focus'` until the time `ngOnInit` is invoked. **To my surprise**, `this.on` throws an error because `undefined has no property 'on'`. So when my directive class is instantiated, for whatever reason, `this === undefined`.

I found one similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104644/modify-angular-2-components-hostlistener-event), though, its looking to dynamically modify HostListener at *runtime* while I just need it modified at *compile/render/instantiation* time.

Can someone please shed light on how I can accomplish this?

Thx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`HostListener` is not dynamic, it can not be changed at runtime. You should use `Renderer` class, which provides `listen` method:

```
@Input()
public on:string;
private dispose:Function;

constructor(private renderer:Renderer, private elementRef:ElementRef){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.dispose = this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, this.on, e => console.log(e));
}

ngOnDestroy(){
     this.dispose();
}
```